# Telerik RadWindow and Response.Redirect - JavaScript Errors

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax, telerik

I have a page with a RadWindow open.  THe RadWindow page executes response.Redirect.  For some reason, when the radwindow redirects, all scripts are failing to load: Sys and JQuery are undefined.  Why would that be?

Thanks.

Comment: Q2, not yet upgraded.  No updates regarding this though according to the release notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is your setup? RadWindow can show content from the main page (i.e. to be used as controls container) or it can display a content page, different from the parent one (i.e. NavigateUrl is set). 
If you are using NaviageUrl, what happens if you don't use RadWindow, but display the content page in a standard IFRAME?

Comment: I'm going to try loading it separately and debug those other scenarios, and get back to you.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it appears something bigger is going on.  Thanks for the assist.